# Got InvocationTargetException when using Guice 4 's createInjector()

Tags: javafx, guice

As a new one to Google Guice, I try to use it in my JavaFX project，the purpose is to inject service to a controller class. But `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` always appears. The main part is here:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Scene scene;
    private static Injector injector;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("ui"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(initilizedClass->{
            return injector.getInstance(initilizedClass);
        });
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    public void init() {
        App.injector = Guice.createInjector(new DiModule());    
    }
//...
}
//
public class DiModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IUserListService.class).to(BroadcastUserListService.class);
    }
}
//
public interface IUserListService {}
public class BroadcastUserListService implements IUserListService {}
//
public class UIController {
    @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    @Inject
    private IUserListService us;
    public void initialize() {
        //listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        us.sendOnlineMessage();
    }
}
```

I use modules and the error details are :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:547)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:890)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:134)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.freelance.ChatterBox/com.freelance.ChatterBox.App.main(App.java:43)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:159)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to module guice
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:192)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at guice@4.0/com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:46)
    ... 49 more
Exception running application com.freelance.ChatterBox.App
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace (formatted as code) in your question.

Comment: An `InvocationTargetException` is thrown when a method or constructor is invoked via reflection and said method or constructor throws an exception. Because of this, the ITE is largely a distraction and you need to look at the `Caused by:`s in the stack trace to find the real error. For more information, see [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627). Please [edit] your question to provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: Can you try the latest version of Guice (i.e. [release 4.2.3](https://github.com/google/guice/releases/tag/4.2.3))?

Comment: Now the version with the problem is 4.0. But when I shift to 4.2.3. My eclipse even couldn't recognize it. Compiling errors. I think the problem starts from: module com.freelance.ChatterBox {
  requires guice; }

Comment: The module for Guice is `com.google.guice`. As far as I can tell Guice is an automatic module. That means the name is derived from the JAR file name or the `Automatic-Module-Name` entry in the JAR's manifest. Not sure what version, but at some point Guice defined the manifest entry to be `com.google.guice`.

Comment: Thank you Slaw. It works. I add ```module com.freelance.ChatterBox {
requires com.google.guice;
exports com.freelance.ChatterBox.service;
}``` and add VM `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=com.google.guice` seems it worked. but in `UIController ` class `IUserListService us` is null! seems `bind(IUserListService.class).to(BroadcastUserListService.class);`doesn't work!

Comment: Two things: (1) Can you show the code that loads the FXML file? You should be setting the [controller factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory(javafx.util.Callback)) to a custom factory that [uses Guice to create the controller instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471185/how-can-i-use-guice-in-javafx-controllers). (2) You may need to add an `opens com.freelance.ChatterBox.service to com.google.guice;` directive to your module-info file.

Comment: Thanks a ton! `opens com.freelance.ChatterBox.service to com.google.guice;` works ! Now there have no errors. But in class UIController: first,  I have to set `private IUserListService us;` to `public`; second, in `initialize()` `listView` is always null. seems  `@FXML` stop working now.